# Excusing parts variables from being executed in PHP

Tags: php, variables, escaping

I have a string which is written to a .txt document using the following code

```
$myfile = fopen("SomeFolder/Cards.txt", "w");
        $txt = "$CardDetail";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
```

The string for `$txt` is from the variable `$CardDetail`

This is what the `$CardDetail` Variable looks like

```
$CardDetail = "

        <div id='CardContain'>
        <iframe id='No' width='364.8' height='220.8' scrolling='no'  frameBorder='0'  src='../Cards/ID/$ID/Iframe2.php'>​</iframe>
        <div id='CardWrapping'>
        <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>CARD ID</b> $ID</h1>
        <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>LAST EDITED</b> $Edited<a id='EditLink' href='../Cards/ID/$ID/Editcard.php'> (edit card)</a></h1>
        <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>DESCRIPTION</b> $Description</h1>
        </div>
        <?php if($KeepVariable == "Exsample"){ echo "<div id='CardStats'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Standby</h1></div>"; }else{ echo "
        <a href='Selectpayment.php?CardID=$ID'><div id='CardButton'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Options</h1></div></a> ";} ?>

        </div>
";
```

I need the following part of that string from `$CardDetail` NOT to be executed and just written to the `Cards.txt` document as it is.

```
<?php if($KeepVariable == "Exsample"){ echo "<div id='CardStats'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Standby</h1></div>"; }else{ echo "
            <a href='Selectpayment.php?CardID=$ID'><div id='CardButton'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Options</h1></div></a> ";} ?>
```

I am not at all expecting anyone to understand what I am trying to explain here. But in simple terms I need to exclude that part of the string from being executed.

Comment: Because all that text is inside of a variable and that executes all the variable names inside it. @Gothdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape variables by `\`, like this:

```
$CardDetail = "

        <div id='CardContain'>
        <iframe id='No' width='364.8' height='220.8' scrolling='no'  frameBorder='0'  src='../Cards/ID/$ID/Iframe2.php'>​</iframe>
        <div id='CardWrapping'>
        <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>CARD ID</b> $ID</h1>
        <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>LAST EDITED</b> $Edited<a id='EditLink' href='../Cards/ID/$ID/Editcard.php'> (edit card)</a></h1>
        <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>DESCRIPTION</b> $Description</h1>
        </div>
        <?php if(\$KeepVariable == \"Exsample\"){ echo \"<div id='CardStats'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Standby</h1></div>\"; }else{ echo \"
        <a href='Selectpayment.php?CardID=$ID'><div id='CardButton'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Options</h1></div></a> \";} ?>

        </div>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the double quotes:

```
$CardDetail = "

    <div id='CardContain'>
    <iframe id='No' width='364.8' height='220.8' scrolling='no'  frameBorder='0'  src='../Cards/ID/$ID/Iframe2.php'>​</iframe>
    <div id='CardWrapping'>
    <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>CARD ID</b> $ID</h1>
    <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>LAST EDITED</b> $Edited<a id='EditLink' href='../Cards/ID/$ID/Editcard.php'> (edit card)</a></h1>
    <h1 id='Cardtext'><b>DESCRIPTION</b> $Description</h1>
    </div>
    <?php if($KeepVariable == \"Exsample\"){ echo \"<div id='CardStats'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Standby</h1></div>\"; }else{ echo \"
    <a href='Selectpayment.php?CardID=$ID'><div id='CardButton'><h1 id='Cardtext1'>Options</h1></div></a> \";} ?>

    </div>
";
```

Comment: Will this stop the variables inside being replaced with text or nothing? @Berriel

Comment: Yes. This won't show the content of the variables, but the result as you said you want.

Comment: Oops, I see you want to show the `$ID` on the final output instead of the content of `$ID`, is this correct?

Comment: The person above uses those escape thing with the variables too that what works but thanks for the help too

Comment: I see you accepted the other answer, but remember, you're not escaping the variables, but the double quotes as I said.